# Unresponsive JavaScript popups. Can I disable them from my website?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to disable browsers popups about long running scripts (i.e. in Firefox and Safari) directly from the website?

(And not from the browser settings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only by breaking the long running script into pieces.

See my answer to  [Show javascript execution progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995805/show-javascript-execution-progress/2995896#2995896) for a solution for this.

Comment: @Patrick: And if the code is triggering those pop-ups, it almost wants to be refactored in this way (broken into discrete chunks and chained) *anyway*.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned Firefox and Safari, you may want to use [Web Workers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-workers/current-work/) (Firefox 3.5 and Safari 4). Execution of Web Workers happens in a separate process, and does not block the UI thread:

- [Mozilla Dev Center: Using web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers)
- [John Resig: Computing with JavaScript Web Workers](http://ejohn.org/blog/web-workers/)

Comment: @Patrick: Just be aware that this is very new stuff and not supported in, you know, That Other Browser. :-)

Comment: Yes, definitely. However it's probably the future of complex JavaScript processing. And not only in the browser - even [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) (on the server-side) is planning to use the Web Workers API to fork new processes.