# JavaScript update a 2MB JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, cordova

How to update a 2MB JSON file using JavaScript?

I use phonegap to develop an Android application. Now, I need retrieve data from a JSON file and then update data back into this JSON file.

It shows me that the "*JavaScript execution exceeded timeout*"

Comment: Can we see your code?  It'll help us understand exactly what's going on

Comment: What does the JSON contain? Maybe JSON is not the best format if you're dealing with large amounts of data on a limited device. Have you thought about using a database like SQLite? Also, does the data come from a server? If so, it's not necessary to send the entire file to the client if it needs only a portion of the data.

Comment: Split the data down to smaller pieces.

Comment: Do you have any more information about the error? The file in question, the line number?

Comment: The same way you do it with XML, CSV, etc.: You parse the data, manipulate the data structure and serialise it back.

Answer (score 1):

Most JavaScript engines have an execution limit, meaning that they will throw an error when your code runs for longer than *x* seconds. In most browsers, this is just 5 or 10 seconds. Have a look at [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3030039/990877) for more information.

Three solutions come to mind:

- **Break up the long-running code** in smaller pieces. Rewrite your algorithm so it works in short "spurts" and use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to call the code in iterations.
- **Use [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers)**, which are specifically designed for long-running tasks. The downside? [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers#Browser_compatibility) is only so-so.
- Run it **on a server**. This may be either trivial  or nearly impossible, depending on your problem.